# Puppeteer Error: Failed to launch the browser process when run in Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I have function `tracking` use Cloud Scheduler run every min, every day deploy in Google Cloud Function.

In this function, I have use puppeteer and mostly function `tracking` run very well but sometimes, my functions have an error

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[0220/073301.661396:ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(201)] Could not bind NETLINK socket: Permission denied (13)
[0220/073301.661935:ERROR:file_path_watcher_linux.cc(71)] Failed to read /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../elf/dl-tls.c: 481: _dl_allocate_tls_init: Assertion `listp->slotinfo[cnt].gen <= GL(dl_tls_generation)' failed!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/srv/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:750:14)
    at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (/srv/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:740:61)
    at emitTwo (events.js:131:20)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
```

[This is the frequency of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHsZ2.png)

- Puppeteer version: v2.0.0 and update newest v2.1.1 yesterday
- Platform/ OS version: Google Cloud Function
- Node.js version: 8

I searched for all the issues of puppeteer but unsolvable my case. Please help me

Thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Answer (score 1):

You need to downgrade your puppeteer version to 2.0.0, it's looks like if there is something which make failed puppeteer when you deploy your app.

You can check
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5379#issuecomment-587185091

For elastic beanstalk worked for me by downgrade puppeteer version.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but my functions when run with puppeteer v2.0.0 still have error :(