# Puppeteet Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Sadly can't get my puppeteer to work on a certain machine, other ones work with the same code (see below).

Any tipps or adivce what to look for or where else to search?

Tried so far:

- reinstall
- headless true/false
- ignoreDefaultArgs
- replacing the chromium files

```
      let browser;
      try {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          headless: false,
          ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
          ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions"],
          args: [
            "--ignore-certificate-errors",
            "--proxy-server='direct://'",
            "--proxy-bypass-list=*"
          ]
        });
      } catch (error) {       
        console.log(error);
      }
```

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (D:\nodeJS\ZDATA\backend\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:750:14)
    at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (D:\nodeJS\ZDATA\backend\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:740:61)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)