# Puppeteer is failing to launch the browser in local

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am getting this error again and again while launching the application. I would have reinstalled puppeteer for like 8-9 times and even downloaded all the dependencies listed in the Troubleshooting link.

Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /home/......./NodeJs/Scraping/code3/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-756035/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT

TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

This Code is just for taking a screenshot of google.com
NodeJs Version- 14.0.0
Puppeteer Version- 4.0.1
Ubuntu Version- 20.04
I am using puppeteer which is bundled with Chromium

````
const chalk = require("chalk");
// MY OCD of colorful console.logs for debugging... IT HELPS
const error = chalk.bold.red;
const success = chalk.keyword("green");
(async () => {
    try {
        // open the headless browser
        var browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        // open a new page
        var page = await browser.newPage();
        // enter url in page
        await page.goto(`https://www.google.com/`);
        // Google Say Cheese!!
        await page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });
        await browser.close();
        console.log(success("Browser Closed"));
    } catch (err) {
        // Catch and display errors
        console.log(error(err));
        await browser.close();
        console.log(error("Browser Closed"));
    }
})(); ```
````

Comment: Can you share your puppeteer script in the question above (especially the `browser.launch()` part)? Also it would be important to know what Node.JS version do you use, which puppeteer version you are installing (e.g.: puppeteer-core or puppeteer (with bundled Chromium)) with which command npm/yarn flags. For first sight it seems a mismatching Chrome/Chromium version with the puppeteer installed.

Comment: @theDavidBarton I have edited as you asked. Please help if you can understand the error

Comment: Your script works perfectly, there must be some dependency issue. Can you try to: (1) uninstall puppeteer npm package with your preferred command (`yarn remove puppeteer` or `npm uninstall puppeteer`); (2) remove `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock`/`package-lock.json` file; (3) install an older version of puppeteer `npm install puppeteer@^2.0.0`? If it solves the issue but you still want to use puppeteer 4+ then we can investigate further.

Comment: One more thing: so `ldd chrome | grep not` doesn't list you more missing packages?

Comment: @theDavidBarton whenever I run the command ```ldd chrome | grep not``` it shows the output ```ldd: ./chrome: No such file or directory```

Comment: @theDavidBarton It is working fine now when I reinstalled the ```puppeteer@^2.0.0```. Thanks man I was stuck with this problem for like 2 days. I am quite new to these things and google does not provide much help in my case. I really appreciate your help. Once I complete my work with the ^2.0.0 I will go for the ^4.0.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said puppeteer 2.x.x works for you perfectly but 4.x.x doesn't: it seems to be a linux dependency issue which occurs more since puppeteer 3.x.x (usually `libgbm1` is the culprit).

If you are not sure where is your chrome executable located first run:

```
whereis chrome
```

(e.g.: /usr/bin/chrome)

Then to find your missing dependencies run:

```
ldd /usr/bin/chrome | grep not
```

`sudo apt-get install` the listed dependencies.

After this happened you are able to do a clean npm install on your project with the latest puppeteer aas well (as of today it will be 5.0.0).