# Launching Chrome with Puppeteer (not Chromium)

Tags: puppeteer

I tried to launch chrome with puppeteer but it gave me this error

> Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn //C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application ENOENT

This is the code I used

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const browser = await puppeteer.launch( { headless: false,
        executablePath: '//C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application' })
```

So how can I launch chrome with puppeteer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path you gave is invalid in this format. If you are on Windows (which I suppose based on your currently given path) (1) you should use double backslashes `\\`, (2) but you shouldn't start your path with slashes nor backslashes. (3) Also you need the exact executable file as well at the end: `chrome.exe`.

The process goes like this: You can retrieve the exact executable path at your Chrome's `chrome://version/` page, then you just need to escape each backslashes with another backslashes.

Correct usage:

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe
```

Comment: my case scenario is on Mac. Could you please advise if I am doing any mistake in the path or what could be the issue? Many thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117723

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me on Windows

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
})
```

The slashes should be forward facing

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add, perhaps what you want is using the package [chrome-launcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-launcher) which takes care of running the chrome browser.

You can then use puppeteer.connect() to connect the puppeteer-core library to the browser opened and instrument it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then try:

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({      
      channel: 'chrome'
})
```