# How to run puppeteer in headless false mode on browser in which node js app runs on ec2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

I am trying to open browser instance on client side , But the client unable to load the browser instance after deploying to the ec2

When attempting to execute Puppeteer in local mode, the browser instance opens correctly. However, after deploying it on EC2, I am unable to observe any browser instances opening on the client side. I encounter the error: "Puppeteer Error: Failed to launch the browser process!" How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Comment: This has been asked many times. Have you tried everything in the existing knowledge base? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117723), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502254), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795309/), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69564238), [6](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/10523), [7](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9941), etc. A [mcve] of your code, even if it's just an import and `puppeteer.launch()` would be great, along with package.json.