# Error: Failed to launch the browser process! Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, puppeteer

I have written some test cases and I am using `puppeteer` on linux with `Docker`. When I try to run it, I can get this below error:

> "before all" hook: codeceptjs.beforeSuite for "Validate_onbord_broker_business":
> Failed to launch the browser process!
> [1230/045642.691806:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

And this is how my `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
# Use whatever version you are running locally (see node -v)
FROM node:12.18

WORKDIR /app


RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
# RUN apt-get install xvfb libnss3 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libxcomposite1 libcups2 libxrandr2 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 -y


RUN wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz"
RUN tar -xzvf jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN rm -rf jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz

# Add rest of the client code
# .dockerignore needs to skip node_modules
COPY . /app



# install manually all the missing libraries
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils

# install chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

# Install dependencies (you are already in /app)
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
# RUN npm ci
RUN npm install
RUN npm install codeceptjs puppeteer


# RUN npx codeceptjs init


RUN npx codeceptjs run 

# CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Can someone please help me, why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: The error contains the answer: `Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported`. Don't run the script as root in the container.

Comment: How can I not run as the `root` in the container?

Comment: Specify a user using the [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) instruction in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I have the issue but using systemd ... i'm using on rasp and i'm using the --no-sandbox .... but nothing ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)