# Puppeteer throws launch exception when deployed on azure functions node on Linux

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, puppeteer, azure-functions-runtime

Problem: Using puppeteer to get the screengrab of a website. Works fine on dev machine but throws below exception when deployed to Azure Functions on the cloud.

Environment: on Azure(Node 12, Linux, Consumption plan), Function triggered using service bus topic.

Error:

```
Result: Failure Exception: Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn 
/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-818858/chrome-linux/chrome 
EACCES TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md 
Stack: Error: Failed to launch the browser process! 
spawn /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-818858/chrome-linux/chrome 
EACCES TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md 
at onClose (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:193:20) 
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:185:85)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20) at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I followed the recommendations that are on puppeteer troubleshoot document but still having the same issue.

Things I tried for lunch setting

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'] });

let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });

let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });   

let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
```

None of the above worked. They all throw the same error.

I checked FTPing into the function and the chrome file puppeteer is looking for, exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you can run the function on your machine?

Comment: @JimXu Yes, The function works fine on my local machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Azure has the necessary dependencies for running headless Chromium in the Linux Consumption plan. So we can use the package `puppeteer` in Azure function. But we need to deploy the app using remote build. For more details, please refer to the [Azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/35161276-allow-running-headless-chrome-or-other-browser-i) and the [blog](https://dev.to/azure/running-headless-chromium-in-azure-functions-with-puppeteer-and-playwright-2fgk).

For example

1. Create Azure function app
   [image]
2. Create Azure function project

a. Install package

```
  npm install puppeteer
```

b. function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mySbMsg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "bowman1012",
      "subscriptionName": "test",
      "connection": "bowman1012_SERVICEBUS"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "outcontainer/{rand-guid}.png",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

c. code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

module.exports = async function (context, mySbMsg) {
  context.log(
    "JavaScript ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message",
    mySbMsg
  );
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://google.com/");
  const screenshotBuffer = await page.screenshot({ fullPage: true });
  await browser.close();
  context.bindings.outputBlob = screenshotBuffer;
};
```

3. Add `.funcignore` file in the root project folder

```
*.js.map
*.ts
.git*
.vscode
local.settings.json
test
tsconfig.json
node_modules
```

4. Deploy to Azure

```
func azure functionapp publish $appName --build remote
```

5. Test
   [image]
   [image]

---

**Update**

Since you use typescript to create Azure function, we need to update `.funcignore` as the following

```
*.js.map
.git*
.vscode
local.settings.json
test
node_modules
```

For example

My function code `index.ts`

```
import { AzureFunction, Context } from "@azure/functions";
import { ServiceBusMessage } from "@azure/service-bus";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";

const serviceBusTopicTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  mySbMsg: ServiceBusMessage
): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const promotionId = context.bindingData.userProperties.promotionId;
    context.log(
      "Player Screen Grabber ServiceBus topic trigger function processing message started",
      promotionId
    );
    const playerURL = "https://www.google.com/";
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(playerURL, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
    const screenshotBuffer = await page.screenshot({
      encoding: "binary",
    });
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    // the storage account connection string
    const constr = process.env["AzureWebJobsStorage"] + "";
    const blobserviceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(constr);
    const containerClient = blobserviceClient.getContainerClient(
      "outcontainer"
    );
    const blob = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(`${promotionId}.png`);
    await blob.uploadData(screenshotBuffer);
    context.log(
      "Player Screen Grabber ServiceBus topic trigger function processing message ended",
      promotionId
    );
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export default serviceBusTopicTrigger;
```

Deploy to Azure

```
func azure functionapp publish $appName --build remote
```

Test

My service bus message
[image]

result
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I go to the edit function bit, It only shows me the TS file apart from that, all the settings are the same as yours. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @VenkataK.C.Tata COuld you please provide a sample code. Let me try it

Comment: Thank you. Apart from the fun ignore file, I don't see any difference from your updated code and mine. Can I know how did you deploy to Azure? I am using azure dev ops. I have a feeling that there is something wrong with the config there. I will share the screengrab of the FTP into function there. Just in case it is different to your one.

Comment: @VenkataK.C.Tata I use Azure function CLI command `func azure functionapp publish $appName --build remote` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#project-file-deployment

Comment: Thanks a lot. I installed the Azure CLI tools and the Az func tools and did the remote build command. For the first time, it works. For some reason, I thought the issue was with the code but looks like, the CICD is doing something different. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @JimXu : Thanks for this. I have a similar use case and followed the instructions. But I'm getting the following error : Exception while executing function: Functions.linuxpdf1 <--- Result: Failure Exception: Could not find Chromium (rev. 1069273). This can occur if either 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/.cache/puppeteer). Am I missing something here? How is puppeteer installed into Azure when I add 
node_modules to the .funcignore thereby removing it from my deployment?

Comment: @AnupamChand, I had the same issue - added the .puppeteerrc.cjs with the `cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, ".cache", "puppeteer")` and it helped.

Answer (score 5):

2023 update to @JimXu's response:

We now also need to specify a [location where puppeteer will be downloaded](https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration#changing-the-default-cache-directory) by creating a `.puppeteerrc.cjs` file:

```js
// .puppeteerrc.cjs
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  cacheDirectory: path.join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer')
};
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this extra information - it was what I needed! Tested with TypeScript Azure Function v4

Comment: I would add to that that it worth adding `.cache` line to `.funcignore` file

Comment: On 10/10/23, I could NOT get this to work until I decided to re-create the azure function using node v16 (downgrading from v18) and it immediately worked.  I am running v18 locally, and it ran on my machine w/o issue.

Comment: Adding this fixed it for me, running fine on Linux with node v18

Answer (score 0):

another update for people who may struggle with remote deployment,
setting `ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD` to `0` will solve build issues