# Puppeteer on Azure Functions Linux throws exception “Failed to launch the browser process!”

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, puppeteer

I'm trying to start a headless chrome with a puppeteer in Azure Functions on Linux.

What do I do? I have a “Function App” that looks this way:

[image: Azure Function App]

And I have a function:

[image: Azure function]

I build this function remotely this way:

```
func azure functionapp publish {appname} --build remote
```

And this is what I get when I try to run a function:

```
Result: Failure
Exception: Failed to launch the browser process!
/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-1011831/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've seen this topic already ([Puppeteer throws launch exception when deployed on azure functions node on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609204/puppeteer-throws-launch-exception-when-deployed-on-azure-functions-node-on-linux)) but they recommend do a remote build, which I do and it still doesn't help.

Maybe I'm using wrong App Service Plan, but I checked and there were nothing related to special linux setup there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that I was indeed using the wrong App Service Plan. I needed a “Function App” one. When I recreated a function with the right service plan, everything worked just fine.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- I was able to deploy the azure function without the use of `func azure functionapp publish {appname} --build remote`. I did it using the visual studio code.
- But before that I installed the puppeteer inside the function folder using

```bash
npm install puppeteer
```

- Then I added the `node_modules` name in the `.funcignore` file.
- Then I added the following setting in `setting.json` in the `.vscode` folder

```
   "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true
```

[image]

- Then deploy the function normally through vscode

[image]