# How to solve Puppeteer: failed to launch the browser process

Tags: puppeteer

Installed Puppeteer using the command : npm install puppeteer
OS : CentOs7 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64
When I tried to run the file, I am getting the following error

(node:14216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/opt/xyz/node-v14.16.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-856583/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libxkbcommon.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How to solve this error ?

Comment: [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Answer (score 4):

It says what is missing:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libxkbcommon.so.0
```

You need to have the library on your system. It seems [this](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libxkbcommon-0.7.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) is the one, you might be able to install it with your package manager:

```
# yum install libxkbcommon-x11
```

Comment: Thanks. `sudo apt-get install libxkbcommon-x11-0` fromhttps://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libxkbcommon-x11-0_0.10.0-1_amd64.deb.html is what I needed.