# Failed to launch browser process using puppeter and docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, puppeteer, chromium

We have used [timesnap](https://github.com/tungs/timesnap) library for capture frames of html pages.

It's working on an ubuntu system, but we pushed this code in aws batch using docker image, then we return the error message below:

> /node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome:
> error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> (node:77) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch
> the browser process!

Below is my docker image sample:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Create app directory

WORKDIR /var/www/html/aws-batch-node/

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
  chromium-browser \
  chromium-chromedriver

RUN apt-get install -y libgbm-dev
RUN apt install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget

FROM node:13.11.0

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN node ./node_modules/puppeteer/install.js

# Bundle app source

COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Comment: Make sure you install these package while running puptter inside docker 
`sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget`

It's required to be able to run it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)