# Puppeteer error: "failed to launch the browser process"

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to run Puppeteer on my new laptop. However, I am getting this error:

```
node:8144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/mnt/c/Users/juliu/repos/kmj-sniper/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-901912/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message can either indicate that your operating system is missing the ATK library (`libatk`), or that this shared library is installed in a location that Puppeteer does not know about, because it is not available from the paths specified in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or has a different name from what is expected.

If the ATK library is missing, what platform your laptop is running will likely determine the answer. If you are running [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), for example, you could do the following, or similar:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0-0
```

On [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)/[RHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux), perhaps:

```
$ sudo yum install atk.x86_64
```

If the required package is already installed, however, check that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` includes the directory where the shared library is installed, and that the filename matches that shown in the error message returned by Puppeteer.

Comment: Thanks this was the answer

Answer (score 2):

Delete folder `node_modules` (don't delete the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files) and then run `npm i`. 
It will essentially reinstall all your dependencies. 
If that doesn’t work, then try [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69564238/puppeteer-error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process/69564284#69564284).