# Puppeteer Fails to launch the browser

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, puppeteer

After creating a directory with an index.js file with the following code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function main() {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
headless: false,
args: ['--no-sandbox']
 });
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://example.com');
await page.screenshot({
path: 'example.png'
});
await browser.close();
}
```

// Start the script
main();

and then running npm init, and npm install puppeteer, the following error is returned:

```
 node index.js
/mnt/c/Users/trgre/OneDrive/Desktop/puppeteer 
test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:214
        reject(new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(`Timed out after ${timeout} ms while trying to 
connect to the browser! Only Chrome at revision r${preferredRevision} is guaranteed to 
work.`));
               ^

 TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to the browser! Only Chrome at 
 revision r901912 is guaranteed to work.
 at Timeout.onTimeout (/mnt/c/Users/trgre/OneDrive/Desktop/puppeteer 
 test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:214:20)
 at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
 at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)

 Node.js v17.1.0
```

Any ideas on what to do in order to run a puppeteer program, I am on windows using Ubuntu 20?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)