# Puppeteer on Centos cPanel: Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have Puppeteer installed on a Centos 7 cPanel and am getting this output with the following error:

```
Starting browser

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/partition_address_space.cc(63) Check failed: false
```

All dependencies are installed. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm running into the same error on Ubuntu 20.04 too.

Comment: Related: [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer), [puppeteer(chromium) cannot work on nodejs production server (cpanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76892831/puppeteerchromium-cannot-work-on-nodejs-production-server-cpanel/76893487#76893487)