# puppeteer(chromium) cannot work on nodejs production server (cpanel)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cpanel

We installed nodejs app with cpnael. We have run our nodejs app on localhost that works fine, but the puppeteer part is not working.

Error:Request Timeout
This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('example');

await page.waitForSelector('#priceSatis', { timeout: 5000 }); // 10 saniye süreyle bekler
// Beklenen element yüklenene kadar bekliyor

const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const a = document.getElementById('priceSatis');
    const b = document.getElementById('priceAlis');
    let c = {
        alis:b.innerText,
        satis:a.innerText
    }
    return c;
});
console.log(result);
await browser.close();
```