# Puppeteer - Failed to launch the browser process! in Windows Service

Tags: iis, windows-services, puppeteer, windows-server-2012

I have a small javascript setup to convert html to pdf using the javascript library puppeteer.

Hosting the service by opening the command panel and starting `node index.js` everything works fine. The express-api hosts the service under the predefined port and requesting the service I get the converted PDF back.

Now, installing the javascript as Windows-Service by using the library `node-windows` and requesting the service, I get the following error message:

```
Failed to launch the browser process!
```

Now I'm not sure where to search for the root cause. Is it possible that this could be a permission issue?

Following my puppeteer javascript code :

```js
const ValidationError = require('./../errors/ValidationError.js')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

module.exports = class PdfService{
    static async htmlToPdf(html){
        if(!html){
            throw new ValidationError("no html");
        }
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
              headless: true,
            executablePath: process.env.EDGE_PATH,
           args: ["--no-sandbox"]
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setContent(html, {
            waitUntil: "networkidle2"
        });
        const pdf = await page.pdf({format: 'A4',printBackground: true});
        await browser.close();
        return pdf;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like a permission issue. Try to set application pool identity to administrator or local system. Then run the JS script again. By the way, when you test the script in local machine, can it launch browser process?

Comment: Ok, it seems that the default service user ```local``` doesn't have the permissions. Changing the user it works.

Comment: So after changing the user, could it work now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)