# Failed to launch the browser process! Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, puppeteer, puppet-enterprise

Puppeter not working on Ubuntu server.
This is my code.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--disable-gpu"],
        headless: false,
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
      });
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer?page=1&tab=trending#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly due to missing Ubuntu dependency

Install all the required dependencies for Puppeteer with the following command.

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb libgbm-dev
```

[Source](https://webcheerz.com/puppeteer-ubuntu-dependencies/)

Comment: I've tried it, but still not working.

Comment: This will happen only if Xvfb dependency is missing. Please try again.

Comment: It is installed

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error msg:

```sh
Missing X server or $DISPLAY
```

You can only run chrome in headless mode by default on the server as it doesn't have a display screen. That's why you get the error.

```js
headless: false,
```

line should be either removed or modified to:

```js
headless: true,
```

There are alternative ways to fake headful mode on the server, but it heavily depends on your environment what works for you and these are non-stable workaround solutions. e.g.

- https://www.mattzeunert.com/2018/07/21/running-headful-chrome-on-ubuntu-server.html
- https://github.com/beemi/puppeteer-headful

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error yesterday.

you have to install and setup x-server as described in this [link](https://www.gregbrisebois.com/posts/chromedriver-in-wsl2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 &
 export DISPLAY=:99
```

Comment: While this may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply