# Puppeteer in Docker - Error: Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: docker, puppeteer

I'm trying to Dockerize my Express API which uses Puppeteer. The server starts listening but when it goes to initialize the bot I get an error.

After running: `docker-compose up`

I get:

```
...
bot-api | Server listening on port: 3000
bot-api | /app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:248
bot-api |             reject(new Error([
bot-api |                    ^
bot-api | 
bot-api | Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
bot-api | /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-991974/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
...
```

Here's my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: bot-db
    volumes:
      - ./docker_postgres_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker_postgres_init.sql
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  web:
    container_name: bot-api
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)