# Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable ENOENT\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING:

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

here is my sample code ,
this code execute in  local without executablePath. But when pass a executablePath and push to elastic beanstalk server then i got this error.

**strong text**
how do i reslove it?`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({     headless: true,       executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',     IgnoreHTTPSErrors: true,     args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--ignore-certificate-errors"],   });`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Answer (score 0):

Your `executablePath` may be wrong, it should be:

```
executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
```

Comment: elastic-beanstalk doesn't support headless chromium. I have tried with the ubuntu machine.