# "Failed to launch the browser process" after Netlify cloud deploy

Tags: deployment, runtime-error, netlify

I’ve deployed the code/[github project] to the Netlify cloud and the draft URL is https://6436c3dc4e53010a66c5489f--nemlig-data.netlify.app

[image]

Yet, when I hit that for the *results.js* serverless function https://6436c3dc4e53010a66c5489f--nemlig-data.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/results
I get the following
[image]

This function has crashed
An unhandled error in the function code triggered the following message:

Error - **Failed to launch the browser process**! /tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory TROUBLESHOOTING: Troubleshooting | Puppeteer

Stack trace

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

TROUBLESHOOTING: Troubleshooting | Puppeteer

at Interface.onClose (/var/task/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:262:24)
at Interface.emit (node:events:525:35)
at Interface.close (node:readline:590:8)
at Socket.onend (node:readline:280:10)
at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Connection details
Netlify internal ID: 01GXRFVPHAZT1SN22WYTCJP9XG
```

### Update

The netlify [serverless function](https://github.com/colbyfayock/my-puppeteer-function/blob/main/functions/results.js) does launch a browser instance. That's why it said: **Failed to launch the browser process**!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to develop & deploy to Netlify using **[Sparticuz/chromium](https://github.com/Sparticuz/chromium)** instead of [chrome-aws-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-aws-lambda) for Serverless Platforms.

Now the function looks like the following:

```
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

chromium.setHeadlessMode = true; 
chromium.setGraphicsMode = false;

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: chromium.args,
        defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
        executablePath: process.env.CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH || await chromium.executablePath,
        headless: chromium.headless,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://spacejelly.dev/");  

    const title = await page.title();
    const description = await page.$eval('meta[name="description"]', element => element.content);

    await browser.close();

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            status: "OK, Done!",
            page: {
                title,
                description
            }
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: what versions of  @sparticuz/chromium and puppeteer-core ? I can't get anything working on node 18 netlify :(