# Puppeteer fails to launch randomly

Tags: node.js, docker, google-chrome, puppeteer

I have a node project running inside a docker container which launches a few puppeteer browsers and I have it deployed on a vps. It randomly fails to launch and once it does, it's very stubborn and might not work afterwards or might work after a long time.

It almost always successfully launches on a clean OS image. However, the issue occurs after that. It occurs on some vps's but not others.

I launch puppeteer like this:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable',
      userDataDir,
      args: [
        `--disable-extensions-except=${path.join(
          extensionDir,
          'extension'
        )}`,
        `--load-extension=${path.join(extensionDir, 'extension')}`,
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        `--proxy-server=${ip}:${port}`,
      ],
    });
```

I'm using `xvfb` to launch chrome in headful mode (`headless: false`).

I get the following error:

```
Error occurred: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[0117/175710.345450:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(354)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting
```

I tried clearing `usrDataDir` and it occasionally works but haven't had much success with it. Also `sudo reboot now`, `docker stop <name> && docker start <name>`, and deleting the docker container/image and rebuilding them doesn't always work either.

The docker container has `--restart=always` and sometimes it doesn't restart which is odd. I'm not sure if it's because it tries to restart the browser too quickly or if it's something else.

Edit:

I also got another error

```
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Target.createTarget): Failed to open a new tab
    at <instance_members_initializer> (/app/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:86:14)
    at new Callback (/app/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:90:16)
    at CallbackRegistry.create (/app/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:22:26)
    at Connection._rawSend (/app/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:80:26)
    at Connection.send (/app/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:74:21)
    at CdpBrowser._createPageInContext (/app/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Browser.js:178:53)
    at CdpBrowserContext.newPage (/app/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Browser.js:303:30)
    at CdpBrowser.newPage (/app/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Browser.js:175:43)
    at ensureLoggedIn (/app/src/index.js:158:32)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Comment: No, I already set the chrome executable path.

Comment: That's just the top answer. It's a canonical thread, so there are 38 answers to try there. Can you confirm you tried all and none apply to your case?

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have a look.