# How to use puppeteer in Docker node:20-alpine

Tags: docker, dockerfile, puppeteer

I've been trying to use puppeteer lately in my dockers and i'm getting this error saying failed to launch process. I've tried to change the image to node:20-slim and some additional packages but still i'm able to see this. please help me out.

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/src/apigateway/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-121.0.6167.85/chrome-linux64/chrome ENOENT


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

    at ChildProcess.onClose (/usr/src/apigateway/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:267:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

take a look at my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    udev \
    ttf-freefont \
    chromium \
    nss \
    freetype \
    freetype-dev \
    harfbuzz \
    ca-certificates \
    fontconfig \
    curl

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/apigateway
WORKDIR /usr/src/apigateway

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/apigateway

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 1337
CMD [ "node", "server.js"]
```

A working docker container. i'm just being greedy here, but I've wasted a long time for this. I desparately needed a solution

Comment: Please add your JS code that start puppeteer, and did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer ?