# VERCEL NEXT JS: Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: node.js, next.js, server, puppeteer, vercel

The application works correctly on my local but not on vercel.
ISSUE FACED HERE:

Failed to launch the browser process!
/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

How to resolve this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)